# Using R for a Date format of 07-JUL-16 06.05.54.000000 AM

Tags: r, date

I have 2 Date variables in a .csv file with formats of "07-JUL-16 06.05.54.000000 AM". I want to use these in a regression model. Should I be reading these into a data frame as factors or characters? How can I take a difference of the 2 dates in each case?

Answer (score 1):

Read them in as characters (e.g. `stringsAsFactors=FALSE` or tidyverse functions), then use `as.POSIXct`, e.g.

```
as.POSIXct("07-JUL-16 06.05.54.000000 AM",format="%d-%b-%y %I.%M.%OS %p")
## [1] "2016-07-07 06:05:54 EDT"
```

(I'm *assuming* that you are intending a day-month-year format rather than a month-day-year format -- but actually I don't have any evidence to support that thought!)

Once you've done this, subtracting the values should just work (give you an object of `difftime`) -- but be careful with units when converting to numeric!

For what it's worth, `lubridate::ymd_hms` *thinks* it can guess the format, but guesses wrong (?? assuming I guessed right above: with a two-digit year, and without any year values greater than 31, there's really nothing to distinguish years and days ...)

Comment: Or read them as factors and feed `as.character(myvar)` to `strptime`.

Comment: I have some code that heuristically tries numerous date formats, and it would do this automagically -- but I only support four-digit years. Ie `%Y` it is and not `%y`.  Not sure if I should change that.

Comment: probably too ambiguous (see my comment above)

Comment: lubdridate failing here could be seen as a feature ;-) -- agree on the awkward nature of two-digit years. To be avoided.

Comment: arguably it should return `NA` in this case, or a warning.  But magic is magic and should be treated accordingly.

Comment: My function does return `NA` when confronted with this input.